# Can the Bernoulli numbers be viewed as a 'renormalization' of a finite geometric series with term $e^{-x}$, by integrating over $(-1,0)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, geometric-series, analytic-continuation, bernoulli-numbers

I was playing around with ways to calculate Bernoulli numbers; for this post I will take their generating function as $x/(1-e^{-x})$, that is,
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{B_n}{n!}x^n = \frac{x}{1-e^{-x}}
$$Here I want $B_1=\textbf{+}1/2$ but it shouldn't really matter. Computing $B_n$ this way often involves L'Hopital's Rule, which I was hoping to avoid.

One way around this is to use the Maclaurin polynomial for $e^{-x}$: to calculate $B_n$, one could replace $e^{-x}$ with its degree $n+1$ Maclaurin polynomial, differentiate $n$ times, and evaluate at $x=0$. For example, to calculate $B_4$, we would put
$$
B_4=\left.\frac{d^4}{dx^4} \frac{x}{1-\left(1-x+x^2/2-x^3/6+x^4/24-x^5/120\right)}\right|_{x=0}
$$
$$
=\left.(14400 \left(7 x^{12}-105 x^{11}+826 x^{10}-4130 x^9+12755 x^8-21700 x^7-4700 x^6+129720 x^5-324800 x^4+432000 x^3-192000
   x^2-144000 x-57600\right)\left(x^4-5 x^3+20 x^2-60 x+120\right)^{-5}\right|_{x=0}
$$
$$
=\frac{-14400\cdot 57600}{120^5}=\frac{-1}{30}
$$If we're game for derivatives of rational functions, we should have faith that this procedure should work since $e^{-x}$ is analytic in a neighborhood of zero.

What I tried to do next doesn't immediately seem like it should work and is the reason for my question. Instead of expanding $e^{-x}$ as a Taylor series, what if we expanded $1/(1-e^{-x})$ as a geometric series?
$$
\frac{x}{1-e^{-x}} = x \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} e^{-kx};
$$one immediate problem is that equality only holds for $\Re(x)>0$. Nevertheless, I decided to truncate this series at $r$ terms and differentiate $n$ times. The derivatives termwise are easy: here are the results for $n=1,\ldots,6$:
$$
\left\{r+1,-r (r+1),\frac{1}{2} r (r+1) (2 r+1),-r^2 (r+1)^2,\frac{1}{6} r (r+1) (2 r+1) \left(3 r^2+3 r-1\right),-\frac{1}{2}
   r^2 (r+1)^2 \left(2 r^2+2 r-1\right)\right\}
$$Now if we integrate these over $-1\le r\le 0$, somehow we get the Bernoulli numbers back:
$$
\left\{\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{6},0,-\frac{1}{30},0,\frac{1}{42}\right\}
$$My question: why is this justified and why does this work?

Comment: This is an interesting question. I will chew on it for a while.

Comment: [This information on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number#Integral_representation_and_continuation) could be related to what you're looking for. To summarize, defining 
$$b(s)=2e^{is\pi/2}\int_0^\infty\frac{st^s}{t(1-e^{2\pi t})}\mathrm{d}t$$
this function has the property that
$$b(2n)=B_{2n}~;~n\in\mathbb{N}.$$

Comment: This link should explain how it works: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BernoulliPolynomial.html Especially equations (29) and (30) should be relevant.

Comment: I'm a little confused - Can you explain why you're allowed to truncate the Taylor polynomial for $\exp$ in the denominator while calculating $B_4$? Aren't you missing out on those higher order terms that don't go away after repeated differentiation? Also can you elaborate a little bit more how you got from
$$\frac{1}{1-e^{-x}}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{-kx}$$
All the way to
$$\{r+1,-r(r+1),...\}$$

Comment: Something I also noticed is that the final list of polynomials in $r$ are very similar to the ones obtained from Faulhaber's formula:
$$S^1_n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}~;~S^2_n=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}~;~S^3_n=\frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4},...$$

Comment: @K.defaoite Looks like the OP lost interest in their question. That happens a lot hereabouts, unfortunately.

Comment: @ProfessorVector apologies, I've been busy. I think I understand what you're getting at: the $n^{th}$ derivatives of $xe^{-kx}$ evaluated at $x=0$ look like $(-1)^{n+1} n k^{n-1}$; if you sum these up for $1\le k\le r$, I think you get $B_n(-r)$, the $n^{th}$ Bernoulli polynomial evaluated at $-r$. Then if you integrate over $(-1,0)$, this should recover the original Bernoulli numbers, yes?

Comment: Yes, of course, though you may be missing a detail or two ;). But that only explains *how* you get the Bernoulli numbers back, not *why* that happens. I mean, you get polynomials as discrete sums over positive integers, integrate that over negative reals, that doesn't sound very rational, now does it?

Comment: Yeah I have to look at it a bit more to understand that.